# Rails SSO - How to make client site automatically login when provider already login, similar to wordpress.com sites?

Tags: wordpress, ruby-on-rails-4, single-sign-on, omniauth, doorkeeper

I had setup SSO using doorkeeper gem and omniauth-oauth2 gem, and now I want to client app to automatically login when provider app already log in, just like wordpress.com site. How can I check logged in status of provider app withauth redirection?